# ifstream error using string as opening file path

Tags: c++

The route of the file this's "/home/Data/Homework 1/file.txt"

```
std::string x = "/home/Data/Homework 1/file.txt"; 
std::ifstream XX(x.c_str())
```

fails.

Comment: And by `fail`, what exactly happens?  Are you certain that that's the pathname to the file, and that you have permission to read it?  How do you know the open has failed?

Comment: Fail - /home/Data/Homework/file.txt ._. the space isn't count

Comment: I don't see why the space in the filename should be causing a problem here, unless the actual file pathname doesn't match what you have written above.

Comment: is the .exe in the same file as your home folder? try just putting the file on your desk top and using a absolute url to the file... ex: C:\Users\Name\Desktop\file.txt something like that. you can fined the url of a file by right clicking on it and going to properties.

Comment: Also, how do you know that the space is causing a problem?  What makes you think it is trying to access `/home/Data/Homework/file.txt`?

Comment: is a dynamic route, but ifstream not work with spaces :(

Comment: because the file exist

Comment: try printing out `std::ofstream << x.c_str()` and see whats in the variable, or inspecting the variable in a debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How `std::ifstream` finds a file given a path is platform-specific, but on a Unix-like system the string should simply be passed to `open`.

You might try debugging a direct call to `open` (from `<fcntl.h>`), and/or check `errno` (from `<cerrno>`) after the `ifstream` constructor returns.

In any case, the problem is almost certainly either insufficient permissions or a spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

The file path you have given might not be correct. Please check that carefully.
In a typcial unix system, the user directory is acount based．That is to see, if your acount name is `Foo`, Then your personal directory should be located at `/home/Foo/Data//Homework 1/file.txt` instead of `/home/Data//Homework 1/file.txt`. But this is not compulsory, so you still can put your files under home directory, which is obviously a bad practice.

So check the actual path, and maybe also check if you have the permission to read the file.